# Object-array inside an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

Well, I'm currently working on a project right now but I have a problem and the problem is that I dont know how to get access to a value inside an object of a variable.

```
var example= {
            "one": [{
                "test": [15,26,56]
            }]
        }
```

What can I do to get access into 15, I tried something like:

```
example.one.test[0]
```

but it didnt work. any hand? :)

Comment: `example.one[0].test[0]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`one` is an array of objects.  So you need

```
example.one[0].test[0]
```

You could also just remove the `[ ]` from the first nest and use it as you were.  That's assuming it is an object you've created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to acces the first array as well

```js
var example= {
            "one": [{
                "test": [15,26,56]
            }]
        };

console.log(example.one[0].test[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. :) It may be probably a dumb question but that's because I'm brand new to this language and it's something new for me. :p

Answer (score 0):

Key `one` is an array with 1 object.Use `example.one[0].test[0]`